# Dolphin Emulator 5 freezing - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, games, freeze, error-handling, debugging

I installed Dolphin Emulator 5 and loaded a game (New Super Mario Bros). The game starts, I can select the level I want to play, then right about when the game should start Dolphin freezes completely. I have tried several other games and the same happens.

At first I thought my computer is to blame, but I have Windows in dual boot, so I went to Windows and installed Dolphin and the games work without any problem in Windows. So clearly my computer is able to run emulated games with Dolphin.

Is there a way to debug Dolphin in Ubuntu? Is there a way to see what causes it to freeze in order to maybe fix it?

Comment: what is your emulation setup of Dolphin? must be the 1rst thing to see

Comment: There are many settings, and for now I haven't changed any of them, so they are the default settings.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with dolphin-emu 5.0 on Debian Buster, amdgpu and Mesa 18.17. I decided to try a newer release from flatpack (5f0d825 is what is shown in the title). I selected Vulkan instead of OpenGL and was able to run the emulators with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a potential answer, but you're probably not going to like it. Basically, the same thing was happening to me, while I was running Ubuntu 18.04.1 with AMDGPU, whether or not I enabled the DC functionality. I also experienced errors unlocking the 1Password X extension in Firefox.

The problems went away when I swapped in a GeForce GTX 960 card and installed the proprietary drivers.

So, I'm going to go ahead and say this is probably a bug in the open source Linux drivers you're currently using, and you'll need to report that upstream, assuming it's not already fixed past the LTS kernel and drivers you're stuck with. Maybe try booting an Arch Linux live DVD, install Dolphin there, and see if it manages to survive about 10 minutes of gameplay there? If so, then it's definitely an issue with the LTS drivers, and since it's a stability issue, it would probably be in Canonical's interest to patch around it.